# how i make listbox and choose the items from it?

Tags: c#

now i try to make some program any way i don't understand this

" how i can make listbox and choose items from it "

i have in the list "manual , antigate , deathbycaptcha"

i need to choose items cuz write user and password

i try to make with switch but i faild :(

```
 string captcha = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            switch (captcha)
            {
                case "Manual":
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Man1");
                        break;
                    }
                case "Antigate":
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Antigate1");
                        break;
                    }
                case "Decaptcher":
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Decaptcher1");
                        break;
                    }
                case "DeathByCaptcha":
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("DeathByCaptcha");
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("can found any thing");
                    break;
            }
```

expected suggestions

### thanks

Comment: What? I have no idea what this question is asking

Comment: You're selecting an index which is a number and comparing it to letter values. It'll never match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use either

```
string captcha = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Or

```
int captchaIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
```

In the code you posted, `captcha` contains a string representation of the `listBox1.SelectedIndex` instead of the item's text.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you really need to get the text for your comparison with:

```
string captcha = listBox1.items[listBox1.SelectedIndex]
```

Then, you may also want to normalize the text by trimming spaces and running the comparison whilst ignoring the case.